# Basic question about CodeIgniter URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I create a controller in CodeIgniter, for example "login.php". I create a public function "index" in it, and load a view "login_form" in the function, the CodeIgniter generates the url `localhost/test/login`.

Now, If i create another function "register" in the same Controller, the url will be `localhost/test/login/register`, but I want to create url like `localhost/test/register`. Do I need to create a new controller register and make the index function in that, or same URL can be generated by adding function in login controller. What is the 'usual' way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned you can (and most likely *should*) use a [route](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) for this:

```
// config/routes.php
$route['register'] = 'test/register';
```

This is basically saying: If `/register` is requested, give them `/test/register`.

Note that `/test/register` is still valid. If you want to disable it for some reason, you can do this:

```
$route['test/register'] = FALSE; // Or map to your 404 page
```

...but in general you won't need to.

Note that use of routes does not magically rewrite your links or anything, it just **routes** the request somewhere else when it is made.

[Remapping](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) is quite cool, but what you're asking is definitely a job for a route. Read the user guide carefully, there's a lot you can do with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following to achieve desired outcome:

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

More information about MVC can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading [this guide](http://www.jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth) on how to extend your controller (in this case `register`) with login check. That would make you have protected code in the `index` function of your `register` controller. And in any other controllers you may want to add. I think in your approach now you are in the risk of having one enourmous `login` controller instead of having several smaller controllers with a bit more structure and overview.